# Spring, @RolesAllowed and database to secure pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have two tabels in my database. User and user_role.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `enable` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
  `user_role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ROLE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_username_role` (`ROLE`,`username`),
  KEY `fk_username_idx` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `user` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

'ROLE' in user_roles show roles which user has{ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN}

I'd like to use @RolesAllowed to deny access for users to some pages(and to grant access for admins) , but I don't have any idea how to get user_role from database and send it to RolesAllowed.

Get user_role in Controller isn't a problem, but I don't think it's good idea to check user role in each function.

Or, maybe, there's a better solution than using @RolesAllowed?

Sorry for the stupid question, it's 5 hours as I have seen Spring for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give much details into the architecture of the application you are building, but as a starter I can give you some samples from the one I am building currently. I am using Spring Boot, JPA, Spring Data and Spring Security. I had a similar requirement and solved it like this:

I have implemented the UserDetailsService interface. It is used to retrieve information about a user that is attempting to log in. As I am using JPA and Spring Data the service and model classes look something like this (getters, setters and most fields deleted for brevity):

```
@Entity
// in your case this would map to the User table
public class Profile implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // you should probably use bean validation / jpa to assure uniqueness etc.
    private String name;
    ...

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles = ImmutableSet.<Role> of(new Role("USER"));
    ...
}

@Embeddable
// in your case this would map to the user_role table
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    public final static Role USER = new Role("USER");
    public final static Role ADMIN = new Role("ADMIN");

    private String authority;

    ...

}

@Transactional
@Service
public class ProfileService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileService(ProfileRepository profileRepository){
            this.profileRepository = profileRepository;
    }

    public Profile loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Profile profile = profileRepository.findByUsername(username);

        // this is the only way to authenticate
        if (profile == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("security.userNotFound");
        }

        return profile;
    }

// you may want to add profile creation etc.
...
}
```

Once I had this set up, I had to configure Spring Security to use this service. I am mostly using Java Config, so configuration looks something like.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ProfileService profileService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(profileService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**")
                .authenticated()
                ...
                // you may want to put more config here
      }
}
```